# Getting error (undefined method) for form_with

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-6

I have _form.html.erb. and on the first line of code, it is throwing this error:

undefined method `assessments_path' for #ActionView::Base:0x00000000229750
Did you mean?  asset_path

couple of points:

1. in routes 'poweruser' is a namespace
2. in models assessment.rb is
   not folder poweruser (as I plan to use it for other pages that anyone can access not just powerusers).
3. Any ideas what I am missing?

Here is the code:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@assessment], local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", resource: form.object %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is the controller

```
module Powerusers
  class AssessmentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    # before_action :set_assessment
    # before_action :set_assessment, only: [:set_assessment, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    # Overwrite any of the RESTful controller actions to implement custom behavior
    # For example, you may want to send an email after a foo is updated.
    #
    # def update
    #   super
    #   send_foo_updated_email(requested_resource)
    # end

    def index
        @pagy, @assessments = pagy(Assessment.sort_by_params(params[:sort], sort_direction))
        # We explicitly load the records to avoid triggering multiple DB calls in the views when checking if records exist and iterating over them.
        # Calling @assessments.any? in the view will use the loaded records to check existence instead of making an extra DB call.
    @assessments.load
    end

    # GET /assessments/new
    def new
      @assessment = Assessment.new
      @assessment.assessment_sections.new
    end
```

here is the assessment.rb (not it is **not** in a sub-folder poweruser)

```
class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :assessment_sections, inverse_of: :assessment
  has_many :questions, through: :assessment_sections

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assessment_sections, reject_if: :all_blank,
                                allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: :all_blank,
                                allow_destroy: true
end
```

Here is the routes

```
  # PowerUser
  authenticated :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
    namespace :powerusers do
      resources :assessments do
        resources :assessment_sections do
          resources :questions
        end
      end
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have namespace in routes, you need to specify that with `form_with`

```
<%= form_with(model: [:powerusers, @assessment], local: true) do |form| %>
```

Comment: many thanks for this.  that did the trick -  It now works.